# SQL Server : conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql-server, procedure

I am creating a procedure in Microsoft SQL Server 2012 but I have a problem. The error message is:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Here is my procedure:

```
DECLARE @name varchar(255)

SELECT name 
FROM sysobjects 
WHERE type = 'P' 
  AND (name LIKE 'pr_My_app_log_%' OR name LIKE 'pr_My_item_log_%') 
  AND (DATEDIFF(dd, getdate(), RIGHT(name, 8)) < -2)
```

There are procedures with these names in my database:

```
pr_My_app_log_20160830
pr_My_app_log_20160829
```

It should be something wrong with DATEDIFF. Can someone help me to correct the query and explain a little bit the issue?

Thank you.

Comment: This is because you have rows in sysobjects where the right 8 characters are not a valid date. Just because the datediff predicate is last in your code does NOT mean the engine will do that check last.

Comment: This won't be foolproof but it will probably be good enough for your purposes:
`and case when right(name, 8) like '20[0-9][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9]' then datediff(dd, getdate(), right(name, 8) end < -2`

Answer (score 1):

When the last 8 characters of the object name cannot be parsed into a `DATETIME`, you are passing the `DATEDIFF` function a non-numeric value.

Try adding a check into your where clause:

```
SELECT name
FROM sysobjects
WHERE type = 'P'
AND (name LIKE 'pr_My_app_log_%' OR  name LIKE 'pr_My_item_log_%')
AND TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, RIGHT(name, 8)) IS NOT NULL -- check for non-numeric
AND (DATEDIFF(dd,  GETDATE(), RIGHT(name, 8) ) < -2)
```

Comment: You need to put the `try_parse()` inside the `datediff()`.